# Read variables value from PLC with Python opcua-asyncio – BadNoMatch: “The requested operation has no match to return.”

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, opc-ua

Edited to correct some typos:
Hi I’m new to opcua-asyncio package so please be patient if I missed something really obvious, I’m trying to figure out how to connect to a Siemens S7 1200 CPU 1212C firmware version 14 PLC from Python (3.11) and read some variables values.
I’m sorry I can’t figure out a way to support my case with a reproducible example because it’s intrinsically connected to the test PLC I’m working with, if you can suggest a way to make it reproducible I’m going to amend the answer accordingly.
The structure on my test PLC is detailed in the picture, I can access it through different clients, the variables from t1 to t19 are my goal.
[PLC Structure][1]
I went through the documentation (especially the [client minimal example](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/master/examples/client-minimal.py) ) and some stackoverflow answers and I wrote the following code

> 

```
# modules
import asyncio
from asyncua import Client


# url and namespace
url = foo bar # the plc location on the network
namespace = "OPC-UA:PLC_1"
t2 =[]


#  I can find the objects inside the node
async with Client(url=url) as client:
    # Find the namespace index
    nsidx = await client.get_namespace_index("urn:OPC-UA:PLC_1")
    print(nsidx)
    root = client.nodes.root
    print("Root node is: ", root)
    objects = client.nodes.objects
    print("Objects node is: ", objects) 

# I can’t find my variables
    var = await client.nodes.root.get_child(
        ["0:Objects", "3:ServerInterfaces", "0:Face"])
    print("Var is:  ", var)
    t2 = await var.get_children_descriptions()
    print(t2)
```

By my understanding of the structure in  OPC-UA:PLC_1 namespace I should find an “Objects” node object listing a “ServerInterfaces” node object listing a “Face” node object listing the variables from t1 to t19. However if I ask “Objects” to describe its childs through  get_children_descriptions() I can see the ServerInterfaces node object however this Serverinterfaces appears to be named “Face”.

If I ask for the childrens of “Face” I receive a BadNoMatch error.
Any help pointing me to the right direction would be much appreciated. Thank you!

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyQCJ.png
```

Comment: Check the BrowseName in UAExpert, because the namespace index must match! 
If this doesn't work you can use the nodeid direct.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Browsename namespace index of Face is wrong.
The index 0 is used for the base nodeset.
You can check the correct index with an other UA Client like the UAExpert (here you need to look at the attibute window not the address space window (which do not show the namespace index)).

If you defined the Face in the face "OPC-UA:PLC_1" the line should be:

```
var = await client.nodes.root.get_child(
        ["0:Objects", "3:ServerInterfaces", "3:Face"])
```